# IEnumerable to Combobox C#

Tags: c#, winforms

How to get the result that IEnumerable and puts it in a combobox?

```
private IEnumerable<Component> EnumerateComponents()
{
    return from field in GetType().GetFields(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic)
           where typeof (Component).IsAssignableFrom(field.FieldType)
           let component = (Component) field.GetValue(this)
           where component != null
           select component;
}
```

Comment: What's stopping you from calling that function and either assigning the result to your combo box's `DataSource` property, or iterating over the results and filling its `Items` property manually?

Comment: he's probably asking, how to do that?

Comment: @DJBurb But that question would just be "how do I set the items of a combo box?", without anything specifically about `IEnumerable`. It's very well possible that you're right, but I'm tempted to say there's also a fair chance that something important is simply not yet present in the question, and that the OP should edit the question to clarify.

Answer (score 1):

Convert it to a list using the .AsList() method and assign it to the Combobox DataSource property.